# how to "auto" enable GPS when app starts?

Tags: cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins

when my app starts I check to see if local GPS is enabled, if not it pops up a question to enable and then directs the user to their settings page to where they must **manually enable** it with:

`cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();`

However, I have seen other apps that when they launch they ask the question and when the user selects 'yes' the app simply just **auto enables** the users GPS without having to take them to their settings page.

How can I replicate this "auto enable" behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (on Android) using a companion plugin of `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` - [`cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy):

Add it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy
```

Then use it:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success){
    console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);
}

function onRequestFailure(error){
    console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
    if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
        if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        }
    }
}

cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Comment: thanks. good to know I can do this.  however, I installed the package but it caused my app to fail when compiling.  I posted a new issue to the plugin github as Issue #1.

Comment: also, I just caught that first note...(on Android).  Is there a similar method plugin that will work for iOS too?

Comment: For compile errors, make sure you have Google play services extras compiled for your build procedure.